# How to restart CLR in C++ when I fail to start the CLR?

Tags: c++, clr, host, gac

I want to use C++ host CLR so that I can configure the default app domain in the CLR
Just like this:

```
HRESULT hr;
ICLRRuntimeInfo *pRuntimeInfo = NULL;
ICLRControl* pCLRControl = NULL;
hr = pCLRControl->SetAppDomainManagerType(
    L"Foo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    L"Foo.Bar");       
hr = gClrRuntimeHost->Start();
```

The `Foo.dll` is supposed to be installed in GAC but what if it is missing?
The `Start()` will fail and I cannot find a way to restart it even if I decide not to use `Foo.dll` to configure the default app domain.

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: Right now you're calling a method on a NULL pointer.  I assume there's some logic you haven't shown, to assign to `pCLRControl`, and that logic is critical to your question (are you willing to repeat it or not?)

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually, that logic is unnecessary in this question. I just want to give information on what type `pRuntimeInfo` `pCLRControl` is. `hr` returned by  `SetAppDomainManagerType` is alway OK no matter if the `Foo.dll` exists in GAC. But `Start` will fail if the `Foo.dll` does not exist in GAC and I cannot restart the CLR anymore.

Comment: Arguably, from the information on the [Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/iclrruntimehost-stop-method) method, it is not possible to do that (maybe depending on the specific error, where you could simply try to call `Start` again). It looks like you'd have to ill/restart the host process - I'm no export, YMMV.